# Select the max value on a multiple table join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get the maximum date out of multiple tables when those table have a particular geometry.
My tables more or less look like that (of course they're all different but I shortened them in order to make it clearer ):

A table type :

```
Id, Info, Geometry, Date
```

And finally I have an other table that looks like that (shortened again) :

B table:

```
Id, Geometry
```

Now, what I want to do is to join all my A type tables on Geometry where they intersect with the B table Geometry, and to get the A table that has the most recent date.

I currently have the following request which is working:

```
UPDATE last_updateT SET date_last_update= S.dateMax 
FROM
    (SELECT B.gid, MAX(A.last_date) AS dateMax
    FROM B
    JOIN A ON ST_Intersects(B.geometry, A.geometry)
    GROUP BY B.gid) S
WHERE T.id = S.gid;
```

Now I'd like to be able to do that kind of join on multiple table that looks like table A. I've heard of the function `GREATEST` but I am not sure about how to use it.
Also, I use `Postgresql` if that makes any differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for `UNION ALL`, so you can treat the data from different tables as if it were data from only one table:

```
SELECT 
  b.gid, 
  MAX(x.last_date) AS dateMax
FROM b
JOIN 
(
  SELECT geometry, last_date FROM a
  UNION ALL
  SELECT geometry, last_date FROM aa
  UNION ALL
  SELECT geometry, last_date FROM aaa
) x ON ST_Intersects(b.geometry, x.geometry)
GROUP BY b.gid;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be exactly what I needed. One small question though, is it the most appropriate way to do it, if my A type tables are extremely heavy ? (millions of rows for some)

Comment: Yes, the approach is okay. Your main problem is anyway that you only find intersecting rows with a function, so the whole tables must be read. As this is the case, `UNION ALL` works just fine here and shouldn't slow this down.

Answer (score 1):

In broad strokes, `MAX` is an aggregate function, so you use MAX to get the highest value from the same column over a number of different rows.

`GREATEST` is a scalar function, you use GREATEST to get the highest value from different columns in the same row.

eg:

```
SELECT GREATEST(col1,col2,col3)
```

Greatest:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html

Max: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html